# Hide window resize button

Tags: cocoa, appkit

When creating an `NSWindow` that has the `NSResizableWindowMask` flag set, Cocoa always draws a resize button in the bottom-right hand corner of the window. This button doesn't integrate very nicely with my custom drawn UI graphics so I'd like to know: Is there a way to tell Cocoa not to draw this button but still keep my window resizable?

Comment: My windows are resizable but don't show a resize button. Show us your code to create the window.

Comment: Ok, right, it looks like newer Mac OS X versions don't show a resize button any longer. On 10.6 (my build system) there is still a quite ugly resize image but on my 10.11 system it isn't there any longer. That's good, so I don't need to find a way to hide it.